# Overload <=> operator ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and don't know if it can be done in ruby.

Can we overload combined comparison operator <=> in ruby for custom class objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can! It would help to google for Ruby's spaceship operator.

You need to include `Comparable` module, and then implement the method. Take a look at simple example of overwriting `<=>`: http://brettu.com/rails-daily-ruby-tips-121-spaceship-operator-example/

I'll take an example from the article:

```
class Country
  include Comparable

  attr_accessor :age

  def initialize(age)
    @age = age 
  end 

  def <=>(other_country)
    age <=> other_country.age
  end 
end
```

For overloading the `<=>` you don't need to include `Comparable` module, however by including it, it "mixins" some useful methods to your `Country` class with which you can perform comparisons.

Let's see some examples:

```
country1 = Country.new(50)
country2 = Country.new(25)

country1 > country2
# => true

country1 == country2
# => false 

country1 < country2
# => false

country3 = Country.new(23)

[country1, country2, country3].sort
# => [country3, country2, country1]
```

But, if the `Comparable` module was not included:

```
country1 > country2
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for #<Country:...>
```

Good luck!

Comment: You can implement `<=>` without including `Comparable`

Comment: Indeed. The relationship is backwards: you need to implement `<=>` when including `Comparable`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Didn't try without including `Comparable`, but I will!